# How to change encoding option in sqlalchemy's create_engine?

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I tried to set encoding option of create_engine function from sqlalchemy, but it didn't work.

I tried :

```
conn = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://myid:mypassword@LAPTOP-5668M0F5:1521/ORCL?mode=2',encoding = "cp949")
```

But after setting the encoding option to 'cp949', the error message still comes up like

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbc in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I don't know why the codec is still 'utf-8' even though I've changed encoding option as 'cp949'.

Comment: Did you mean to pass `encoding` / `nencoding` to cx_Oracle driver? If so, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096324/pass-encoding-parameter-to-cx-oracle-from-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 0):

Try, before connect:

```
import os
os.environ["NLS_LANG"] = '.cp949'
```

I using:

```
import os
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
os.environ["NLS_LANG"] = '.AL32UTF8'
engine = create_engine("oracle+cx_oracle://USERNAME:PASSWORD@ADRESS:1521/ORCL?charset=utf8", echo=True)
SQLText1 = "SELECT 'Test' FROM dual"
conn = engine.connect()
df = pd.read_sql_query(SQLText1, engine)
df
```

Try: charset=cp949