# Unicode issues with Pandas and SQLAlchemy using Oracle Database

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to read csv file using pandas and write it into oracle database

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchmey types, create_engine

df = pd.read_csv("abc.csv")
df.dtypes
Name object
CName object
price float64

df.head(2)
Name    CName  price
Gary    ALS    13.0
John    Ülka   19.9

engine = create_engine('oracle://+ xxx + xxx + 'connection string')
connection = engine.connect()
df.to_sql(name='test-tbl', con=connection, index=False, if_exists='append')

 File "/apps/anaconda/4.6.14/envs/TST/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1468, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/apps/anaconda/4.6.14/envs/TST/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 154, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/apps/anaconda/4.6.14/envs/TST/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1224, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/apps/anaconda/4.6.14/envs/TST/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/oracle/cx_oracle.py", line 1080, in do_executemany
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xea' in position 23: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Currently I am using python3.6 to test the above code, seeing the errors in above.Is any one can help to fix this ?

package versions :
pandas-1.0.3
cx_oracle-6.4.1
sqlalchemy-1.3.5

CSV file format in UTF-8

Comment: Did you `CHARACTER SET` the oracle database?

Comment: No, I didn't. Code works well with python2.7, but I have to use python3.6 from now onwards.

Comment: Try forcing the encoding when reading the CSV. Try with encoding='utf-8', encoding='latin1', encoding='iso-8859-1' or encoding='cp1252'...

Comment: sure. I have tested with encoding='utf-8', but no luck. I 'll try with other ones and let you know.

Comment: Have you got NLS_LANG set?  Or used https://stackoverflow.com/a/53738233/4799035 (probably with UTF-8 for general usage)?  Or maybe you can upgrade to cx_Oracle 8 which uses UTF-8 by default.

Comment: Hi Chris, I have passed the connct_args while creating the engine with UTF-8.          "encoding": "UTF-18","nencoding": "UTF-8".Its worked.Thanks for your help !

Comment: Does the following solution work for you? [Answer to how to use `charset` and `encoding` in `create_engine` of SQLAlchemy (to create pandas dataframe)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49169477/10521959)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Copying the comments for visibility as the solution)

The solution was to use something like:

```
import cx_Oracle
e = create_engine(
    "oracle+cx_oracle://un:pw@connstr...",
    connect_args={
        "encoding": "UTF-8",
        "nencoding": "UTF-8"
    }
)
```